# c++ implicit type conversion between intrinsic types

Tags: c++, type-conversion

In C++ binary operators for intrinsic types, both operands should have the same type, if not, one of the operands get converted to the other operand's type based on a hierarchy:

```
long double
double
float
unsigned long long int
long long int
unsigned long int
long int
unsigned int
int
```

My Question is: Why `unsigned T` is in a higher level than `T` . is it just an arbitrary choice or there is some advantages in converting `T` to `Unsigned T` and not the other way around.

**Update:**

```
//where `unsigned int` to `int` work better.
int a=-3;
unsigned int b=3;
cout << a+b; /* this will output the right result if b get converted to int,
which is not what really happen.*/
```

---

```
//where `int` to `unsigned int` work better.
int a=3;
unsigned int b=pow(2,20);
cout << a+b; /* this will output the right result if a get converted to unsigned int,
which is fortunately what really happen.*/
```

So I dont see how convering `T` to `Unsigned T` has more advantages than the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is essentially an arbitrary choice that goes back to the early days of C.

As far as I can determine, in pre-standard K&R C the rule basically was that if an operand of a operator had a unsigned type, then the result would also be unsigned (this is called unsigned-preserving).

When C got standardized, this rule was changed to the rule currently used by both C and C++, which allows the unsigned property to get dropped, as long as the value can be represented in the target type (this is called value-preserving). The reason was that the new rules provide fewer surprises for the unsuspecting programmers when doing mixed signed/unsigned arithmetic.

The conversion from `T` to `unsigned T` can have two interpretations:

1. It is a hold-over from the old (unsigned preserving) rules.
2. It is the only sane thing to do that does not require a type larger than `unsigned long long` for stuff like: `1ULL > -1LL`, because the signed to unsigned conversion is always defined (by virtue of the wrap-around feature of unsigned integers), but the reverse conversion is not.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the logic is that the actual size of `int` is 1 bit less than of `unsigned int` since the MSB is used for sign. Thus the range of absolute values of signed variable is half the range of the unsigned one.

Comment: that's not true, they both can represent pow(2,32)-1 different values.

Comment: @AlexDan of course, that's why I was referring to absolute values (and I wrote "I would guess that the logic...")